# Downloading an App From Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

From what I've read, only the owner or the uploader may download an application from Google App Engine. I've been marked as the 'owner' and have been trying to download an app to no avail.

When I run this command:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A application_id -V 1 some_directory
```

I simply get:

```
07:29 PM Host: appengine.google.com
07:29 PM Fetching file list...
07:29 PM Fetching files...
```

and then that's all. Shouldn't it be prompting me for an email and a password? Any and all help would be appreciated... I'm a little lost.

EDIT - I've also tried this:

```
appcfg.py download_app --no_oauth2 -A application_id -V 1 some_directory

Email: ***@***.com
Password: ********
```

I still get the same message with no download :(

Comment: are you sure that downloading code was not blocked? if so, you can't revert that setting.

Comment: That's probably it...